# Sails Consistency violation with simple Controller attribute

Tags: exception, controller, sails.js, action

In a Sails 1.x app, add a property to a controller, initialize it with a boolean, a number or `null` and try to lift the app.

```
module.exports = {
    _foo: 123, // illegal
    _bar: '', // legal
    _baz: [] // legal
};
```

The lift will fail with this message:

```
error: Failed to lift app: Error: Consistency violation: `action` (2nd arg) should be provided as either a req/res/next function or a machine def (actions2), but instead, got: ...
```

However, an empty string, empty array, empty object etc. work.

Am I misunderstanding something fundamental about controllers or why are booleans and numbers not allowed?

My goal is to add simple attributes to the controller in order to temporarily store information.

Comment: I usually put everything inside fn:async function () { ... }  Any information that requires to be stored ( temporary or not ) goes into a Model. If you have system wide constants, you can create a config file with them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Action 2 controllers follow the Node Machine structure:

https://node-machine.org/spec/machine

### Helpers

For dynamic content, then the better option could be to use helpers:

https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/helpers

For example:

```js
// api/helpers/custom.js

module.exports = {
  friendlyName: 'Format welcome message',
  sync: true, // without this use await sails.helpers.custom
  fn: function(inputs, exits, env) {
    return {
      data: 'example'
    }
  }
}
```

Access this info in the controller as `cons data = sails.helpers.custom();`.

### Config

For constants, you could use a config file:

https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/configuration

For example:

```js
// config/custom.js

module.exports.custom = {
  data: 'example'
}
```

Use this data in the controller as `const data = sails.config.custom.data; // result 'example'`